# Android 2.3.4 Tablet U1 Files Client first login failure

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I have installed (then uninstalled/reinstalled) the U1 Files client app to my generic Android 2.3.4 tablet.  Every time I try to launch the app and get to the login screen I get the error

```
Authentication Failed: org.apache.http.client
HttpResponseException: UNAUTHORIZED
```

I have tried to sync a photo from the gallery (share via U1) as posted in another question in this forum to no avail.

The U1 Files Client app works just fine on my HTC EVO, now I need it to work on my tablet.  What workaround do I need to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

1. Device > Settings > Manage applications > Ubuntu One Files > Force close, Clear app data
2. Device > Settings > Accounts & sync > remove the Ubuntu account
3. Device > Settings > Date & time > Automatic -- checked
4. relaunch Ubuntu One Files and try again

If you have further issues, please contact us [using this form](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Samsung Galaxy Gio. Setting  the Date and Time right solved the problem!

Comment: This could certainly cause some authentication failures: OAuth signatures include a time stamp, so if your clock is too far out of sync it could cause the authentication info to be rejected.